# is there a way to applescript (or elsescript) acrobat XI to perform OCR?

Tags: applescript, ocr, acrobat

There are many examples for the X version, but they do not work with XI and that's due to the fact that those examples worked with menu item, while Adobe into the XI moved OCR tool away from menu. So I do not have any idea how could use applescript to tell Acrobat XI to perform OCR on certain files.

My final goal is to set a watched folder with Hazel to automagically OCR every PDF I put into that, please do not tell me to use PDFPen, I do not like it, I just would like the OCR special powers of Acrobat ;-)

Thank you.

– cordialmente,

tiziano solignani, da  Mac
http://blog.solignani.it

Answer (score 0):

The UI between Acrobat X and XI didn't change, and the "Execute Menu Item" command will still work even though you don't see the menu items (think of them as "hidden").

Comment: Uhm, but how do I reference the menu item? I guess you should insert the menu item's *number*: if there is no (visible) item which number should I refer to? Thank you.